# Pulling a HTML string from an Excel sheet and updating VBA Variables in it

Tags: vba, excel

I have a need to pull a HTML string from an Excel sheet and update a variable in that string with a current value before sending as an email.  
Let me explain with an example:
I have a worksheet that has a cell (A1 & B1) with values:

```
  IMEI: " & Me.IMEI & "<br>
  Name: " & Me.FullName & "<br>
```

In VBA I'm creating a String which will become the body of the email:

```
  Body = Body & Worksheets("Worksheet").Range("A1").Value<br>
  Body = Body & Worksheets("Worksheet").Range("B1").Value<br>
```

Now, in `VBA`, Me.IMEI and Me.Fullname are correct values that have been pulled from a Userform `(e.g. "12.345678.876543.2" and "User, Test")` and I want to update the strings with the actual values, rather than - as happens now - Me.IMEI and Me.Fullname are inserted in the body.

Or, is there a better way altogether to do this that doesn't require hardcoding the text of the email in the macro?  (I have to get the macro signed by our central office and want the ability to change the text of the email that is created without having to get it resigned everytime that happens).

Comment: maybe read the body text from a txt file that has been seeded with unique merge field markers you use for search & replace.

Comment: are you trying to insert the string "Me.IMEI" into you code from a cell in the Excel Sheet?

Comment: instead of setting the value in the cell, call `Me.IMEI` directly in the vba code.

Comment: @dzman No, I'm trying to replace Me.IMEI with the actual value of the variable Me.IMEI which is already defined in VBA.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Me.IMEI in the cell is just a part of a larger body of text, I just need the actual value subsituted in.

Comment: one "messy" way might be to create a custom function that returns the Me.IMEI value when called. e.g. IMEI: " & " & GetIMEI() & "<br>

then the function in VBA could be 
function GetIMEI()
return Me.IMEI
end function

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the comments correctly, and Me.IMEI is a user input on a userform, could you not just write the values of your hypothetical Cells A1 & B1 dynamically by using the following?

```
Sheet1.Cells(1,1).Value = "IMEI: " & Chr(34) & " & " & Me.IMEI.Value & " & " & Chr(34) & "<br>"
```

Depending on what userform control Me.IMEI is and what you are trying to extract, you might need Me.IMEI.value or .caption or .text

Comment: Problem with this is that I don't want to write it out to cells, instead I'm composing an email, the template for which is pulled from a worksheet (or txt file, doesn't really matter) and wanted to use variables names in the template, having them extrapolated to their actual values during the composition of the email.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up, at this point, just using a series of REPLACE() statements to catch all the tags that I might want to use.  Seems like a fairly awful way of doing it, but it's still more dynamic than having the email text hardcoded (and thus uneditable) in the macro itself.  Hopeful I can come up with a more elegant solution for my next release.